# how to transform html element programmatically in angular 5

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to transform the html element programmatically. Updated transform value changed in console-tab but not changed in element-tab in the browser.

```
onDragStart(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.elementRef = element;
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
    this.translateY = matrix.m42;
    console.log(this.translateY) //outputs: 85, because its current Y-location is 85px 

    element.style.transform = "translate( 0px," + this.translateY + "px)";
    console.log(element);    
  }
```

where I am wrong? I am facing this issue about last 24 hours.

Comment: Just use a variable and change the name? `this.text = '';` and `this.text = "translate( 0px," + this.translateY + "px)";`. In the html you can do `{{text}}`

Comment: actually I am inserting multiple html-elements programmatically using *ngFor so this {{text}} will be changed for all of them. Isn't it?

Comment: Plz read: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntactically and logically the question was correct.

Actually I have not set the `top`-attribute of the html-element that's why it was behaving non-ideally (going at location translation(0px,0px) from its current location) on first click.

First set `top`, then `transform` it anywhere because setting `top` sustains its first position and then you may translate it somewhere